# Problemas com PDO em php

Tags: php

Boa Tarde, estou tentando acessar meu banco de dados ara pegar os 12 países presentes na tabela e retornar um array com os o id e nome dos 12 paises mas meu código esta somente retornando 1 posicao no array que é o primeiro pais somente, alguem poderia me ajudar por favor. Desde ja agradeço

```
function recuperaPaises(){
    //Função que pega os países do banco e jogam no array de países da classe
    $conexao = new DB;
    $conexao=$conexao->getConnection();
    $rs = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM paises");
    if ($rs->execute()){

  $row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  return $row;

}
else{

  $flash="OPS!... ouve algum erro em nosso Sistema. Por Favor contate administrador!";
  echo $flash;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para retornar todos os itens de uma consulta [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) utilize o método [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php), porque se colocar somente [fetch()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php) é para retornar apenas um item do resultado, geralmente na busca de dados de 1 cliente, dados de uma compra, etc, ou seja, para trazer uma coleção de dados utilize [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php), ***exemplo***:

***Código modificado:***

```
function recuperaPaises()
{
    //Função que pega os países do banco e jogam no array de países da classe
    $conexao = new DB;
    $conexao=$conexao->getConnection();
    $rs = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM paises");
    if ($rs->execute()){

      $row = $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      return $row;

    }
    return null;
}
```

Fiz uma modificação se não trouxer resultado retorne `null` fora dessa chamada de método se pode trabalhar melhor as informações de retorno.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [PDO - fetch()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php)
- [PDO - fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php)